# Java program that gives prime numbers between two intervals

Tags: java

I need a program that prints all the prime numbers between any two intervals and than prints how many prime numbers there were between the two intervals.

So I have a running code but it won't print the number 2 and I know 2 is a prime number. It's doing everything else correctly. I tried some other codes that would print 2 but it would also give negatives if I put in a negative number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    int first, last, flag = 0, i, j;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("\nEnter the lower bound : ");
    first = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\nEnter the upper bound : ");
    last = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The prime numbers in between the entered limits are :");

    int x = 0;
    for (i = first; i <= last; i++) {
      for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
          flag = 0;
          break;
        } else {
          flag = 1;
        }
      }
      if (flag == 1) {
        x++;
        System.out.println(i + " ");
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Total number of prime numbers between " + first + " and " + last + " are " + x);
  }
}
```

So if I was to put in -5 (upperbound) and 10 (lowerbound)
It should print:
2
3
5
7
Total number of prime numbers between -5 and 10 are 4

But instead it prints
3
5
7
Total number of prime numbers between -5 and 10 are 3

Comment: Time to learn to use a debugger!

Comment: Just make a special case and check for `i == 2`

Comment: step 1: when you get negative input, first, and immediately, rewrite it to `2` before doing anything else. Because by definition there are no prime numbers less than 2. Second, if you wrote this code yourself, you should be able to explain what happens at each line and why. It's basically only 6 lines of code, so manually run through it: get pen and paper, and just run through what happens with inputs min=2 and max=10. What values do i and j start and end at, on each line? what does `flag` do? This takes only a few minutes to work out, and will let you discover the problem very easily.

Comment: The code works with no errors, it just didn't print 2. 
when I played with my conditions to print 2, it would mess with the rest of the prime numbers I needed it to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following lines before your `for` loop and it will give your the expected output:

```
int x = 0;
if (first<3) {
    System.out.println(2);
    x++;
}
```

Your updated program will be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    int first, last, flag = 0, i, j;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("\nEnter the lower bound : ");
    first = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\nEnter the upper bound : ");
    last = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The prime numbers in between the entered limits are :");

    int x = 0;
    if (first<3) {
        System.out.println(2);
        x++;
    }
    for (i = first; i <= last; i++) {
      for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
          flag = 0;
          break;
        } else {
          flag = 1;
        }
      }
      if (flag == 1) {
        x++;
        System.out.println(i + " ");
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Total number of prime numbers between " + first + " and " + last + " are " + x);
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked great, so simple yet so effective. I had tried something similar inside the for loops but it just gave me wrong outputs. Thanks!

Comment: I'm new to the site so I didn't know how to mark the answer accepted, figured it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

inner loop ignore number 2.
j < i => 2 < 2 is false

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code (optimized as it will run faster for big ranges. Loop returns before iterating all the numbers)

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        int first;
        int last;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nEnter the lower bound : ");
        first = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\nEnter the upper bound : ");
        last = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The prime numbers in between the entered limits are :");

        int x = 0;
        for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                x++;
                System.out.println(i + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total number of prime numbers between " + first + " and " + last + " are " + x);
    }

    static boolean isPrime(int n)
    {
        if (n <= 1) //less than 2 are not
            return false;
        if (n <=3) // 2 and 3 are prime
            return true;

        if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0)
            return false;

        for (int i = 5; i * i <= n; i = i + 6)
            if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0)
                return false;

        return true;
    }
```

You do not need a flag.

Comment: The only problem this one gave me is that the number 3 wouldn't print which is also a prime. However I was able to solve that problem by adjusting one of your lines that printed 2 as prime to: 

        if (n == 2 || n == 3) // 2 is prime 
            return true;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i, n;
        int num;
        int maxCheck;
        boolean isPrime = true;
        String primeNumbersFound = "";

      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
        num = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
        maxCheck= sc.nextInt();

        for (i = num; i <= maxCheck; i++) {
            isPrime = CheckPrime(i);
            if (isPrime) {
            primeNumbersFound = primeNumbersFound + i + " ";
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Prime numbers from " + num + " to " + maxCheck + " are:");

        System.out.println(primeNumbersFound);

}

public static boolean CheckPrime(int n) {
    int remainder;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        remainder = n % i;
        if (remainder == 0) {
        return false;
          }
        }
        return true;

        }
}
```

Comment: This one gives me the correct prime numbers if the lower input if 2 or above but includes negatives if I start my lower interval with a negative